# Get an objects embedded value, given the path as a string

Tags: c#, reflection

I know that you can use reflection to get a property value, given the property name. However, if I have a string such as `"Case.Contact.Fax"` how can I parse the `Case` object to get the `Fax` number.

Comment: Show the code you have so far and what exact problem you have

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, given the string "Case.Contact.Fax" or "What.What.What" are you trying to instantiate an instance of the first token delimited by .?

Comment: I am extracting case data from SFDC. The case object is linked to contacts, so I can't do this for example    Case.GetType().GetProperty('Case.Contact.Fax').GetValue(Case, null) .will post code later

Comment: Given that you know to use reflection to get a named property. Are you saying you don't know how to split a string by `.`?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (caseObj is Case)
{
    var contact = caseObj.GetType().GetProperty("Contact").GetValue(caseObj, null);
    var faxValue = contact.GetType().GetProperty("Fax").GetValue(contact, null);
}
```

or simply:

```
if (caseObj is Case)
{
     var faxValue = (Case as caseObj).Contact.Fax;
}
```

or if you can't get `caseObj` type but you are sure it is always `Case`:

```
var faxValue = (caseObj as dynamic).Contact.Fax;
```

Assuming none of the properties in the tree are ever `null`.

Comment: The first part won't work as the second `GetType()` will return `PropertyInfo` which doesn't contain the property `Fax`. You need to GetValue at each stage.

Comment: Still not quite right. The value passed to the Fax property needs to be the contact, not the case